# Yellow, Green, Red icons with contacts and with sms messages

Tags: contacts, sms

I have seen these icons coming in front of sms messages and in contact list. What they stand for?

These icons are just like a "clock"

Comment: What kind of phone/device do you have? This seems like something that could potentially be part of a manufacturer's UI (TouchWiz, Sense, Motoblur, etc).

Comment: I am using Huawei Ideos - http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_u8150_ideos-3513.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon refers to that contact's "availability":

> - Green: Available. You are online and ready to chat.
> - Yellow: Idle. Your status automatically changes to idle when
>     you're away from your computer for 15
>     minutes. You can't manually select to
>     appear idle
> - Red: Busy. This lets your contacts know you're busy and don't want to be
>     interrupted
> - Grey: Signed out of chat, or Invisible. If you set your status to
>     Invisible, you'll appear to be signed
>     out of chat even when you're actually
>     signed in.

Source: [Google Chat support](http://www.google.com/support/chat/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=161809) answer